# How to classify points in mapinfo table into their enclosing polygons (non overlapping polys) in one run

Tags: mapinfo, select, mapbasic

The objective is to classify a group of points to its enclosing polygons in one run rather than using select for each polygon and do it on one by one basis (for 100,000 point and 5000 polygons it can take for ever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example should help. You can use an SQL query using a geographical operator such as 'within' or 'contains'.
http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-oct-2012/Query-Ninja-Joining-Tables

Comment: You might want to use this link to the new Community as the other Archive will be closed down soon: https://li360.pitneybowes.com/s/article/ka180000000DAl6AAG/Query-Ninja-Working-with-data-from-multiple-tables-using-joins-Part-One